# how to print a specific line of a csv file in python based on user input?

Tags: python, excel, csv

Currently when the user inputs a number, rather than printing the text in that line it prints all numeric values.

```
file = open ("movies-wk5.csv")
print("type a number between 1 and 158")
movie_ID = input()
for response in file:
     datalist = response.split(",")
     movie_ID = datalist[0]

readline(movie_ID)
```

Comment: So if a user inputs a number, say 100, are you expecting to print the 100th line in your csv file?

Comment: exactly yeah not the number 100 but only that line in the file

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `range` with your user input to skip to the line desired:

```py
# Convert this to an int
movie_id = int(input("Type a number between 1 and 158: "))

with open("movies-wk5.csv") as fh:
    # need a -1 here because items are 0 indexed
    for i in range(movie_id - 1):
        # next() will consume the next line in the file
        _ = next(fh)

    # grab the line you wanted
    line = next(fh)
    print(line)
```